# Count rows starting in the middle of worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question about the cell count in vba for excell workbook. I am trying to write down text selected in combobox to a proper row (row 26 in the picture) in excel with changing it if it is full (move to next row) till row 32. If it reaches row 33, write text in error window (not enough space). For better wiev and understanding I make a picture where it is all expained. Currently i use following code but it is hot working well:

```
Private Sub btnvzdrzevalna_Click()

Dim nvdsheet As Worksheet

Set nvdsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("iNVD")

nr = nvdsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 15 
'- 15 leads to the right cell from bottom of last cell but it allways returns the same cell because the last cell in rows.count is the same so it overwrites it. 

nvdsheet.Cells(nr, 2) = Me.cmbvzdrzevanje
nvdsheet.Cells(nr, 3) = "Stanovanjski zakon (SZ-1)"
nvdsheet.Cells(nr, 4) = Me.cmbizvajalec2
nvdsheet.Cells(nr, 5) = Me.cmbperioda
nvdsheet.Cells(nr, 6) = Me.cmbpregled
nvdsheet.Cells(nr, 8) = Me.tbcena1

End Sub
```

The picture for better understanding of question

[image]

Thank you for your help. Have a nice day,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with these modifications:

```
Private Sub btnvzdrzevalna_Click()

Dim nvdsheet As Worksheet
Set nvdsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("iNVD")

Dim nr As Long
nr = 26

With nvdsheet

    'finds first empty row starting at 26, but not moving past 33
    Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(nr, 2)) Or nr = 33

        nr = nr + 1

    Loop

    If nr < 33 Then

        .Cells(nr, 2) = Me.cmbvzdrzevanje
        .Cells(nr, 3) = "Stanovanjski zakon (SZ-1)"
        .Cells(nr, 4) = Me.cmbizvajalec2
        .Cells(nr, 5) = Me.cmbperioda
        .Cells(nr, 6) = Me.cmbpregled
        .Cells(nr, 8) = Me.tbcena1

    Else

        MsgBox "Not Enough Space"

    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank your for yout help. Now it works perfect and I understand how to make that for next time. Your answer was really helpful for my project. Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 0):

the question is unclear but, cmbvzdrzevanje, cmbizvajalec2 etc.. are form controls? (comboboxes etc..). if they are, you need to use the text property.

```
    .Cells(nr, 2) = Me.cmbvzdrzevanje.text
    .Cells(nr, 3) = "Stanovanjski zakon (SZ-1)"
    .Cells(nr, 4) = Me.cmbizvajalec2.text
    .Cells(nr, 5) = Me.cmbperioda.text
    .Cells(nr, 6) = Me.cmbpregled.text
    .Cells(nr, 8) = Me.tbcena1.text
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice and reminder for the property but it is already set in database.